# Slicing Columns of a Data Frame by Name

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

Is there a way to slice columns in data frame when I want multiple consecutive columns? I also want to be able to slice the rows at the same time. The below example shows the call I would like to find an equivalent to.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd


data = np.random.randn(10, 4)
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['A', 'B', 'C', 'D'])

print(df.loc[1:5, ['A', 'B', 'C']])  # Works
# print(df.loc[1:5, ['A':'C']])  # Is there a syntax that allows this?
```

Comment: `df.loc[1:5, 'A':'C']`?

Comment: Oh come on. I was so close. When you're doing it as a list you need the extra brackets and I didn't try dropping them. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The correct call is

```
print(df.loc[1:5, 'A':'C'])
```

Thanks to @Henry_Yik for the answer.